# The signature of a function that returns any instances of a particular class

Tags: haskell

There are a class and an instance of the class.

```hs
class Vehicle a 

data Car = Car 
instance Vehicle Car
```

I would like to define the method `break` that returns **list of any instances of the `Vehicle` class**. In which way, can I do it?

```hs
break :: (Vehicle a) => [a]
break = let
    c1 = Car {}
    in [c1]
```

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Car’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      Main.break :: forall a. Vehicle a => [a]
    at jdoodle.hs:6:1-27
• In the expression: c1
  In the expression: [c1]
  In the expression: let c1 = Car {} in [c1]
• Relevant bindings include break :: [a] (bound at jdoodle.hs:7:1)

  |
9 |     in [c1]
  |         ^^
```

Comment: That makes no much sense: it is not even said that the instances of `Vehicle` are real "concrete" types. For example `instance Vehicle Maybe`, is not a `Just` or a `Nothing`, it is a type that still requires a parameter to be turned into a concrete type.

Comment: The signature `Vehicle a => [a]` furthermore does *not* say, a list of items where each one is a `Vehicle`. It basically says: for every type `a` that is an instance of `Vehicle`, I can produce a list of items of that type, so if you would use it as a `Car`, it is supposed to return a list of `Car`s, but if one would ask it to generate a list of `Train`s, it should return a list of `Train`s.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem What is the canonical way of returning list of Train and Car and whatever in Haskell? In java, it might be done with using common interface.

Comment: it makes not much sense, a `class` is not really what it is in Java, and it is not said that the instances have a singleton data object, or map to a real type. For example we can make a `data SomeTrain a = Train`, and make it `instance Vehicle SomeTrain`, but then what would `a` be, `()`, `Int`, `Char`, but a `SomeTrain ()`, and `SomeTrain Int`, are thus different types, and since `a` can be any type, the number of possible values is unlimited.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I got your idea. However, in some cases information about `a` types is not interesting, e.g. when we are using `Show` class. We don't want to know a particular type, we just want to know that we can invoke `show` function for these objects and then to use strings.  
Personally, I found it quite confusing that Haskell doesn't let do it in laconic way.

Comment: it doesn't because it would be non-sensical. It would require all sorts of hetrogenous lists, boilerplate logic, etc. to _work_ with these items. `Vehicle a => [a]`, does *not* say "a list of instances with types that are all instances of `Vehicle`, it says a list of items all of the same type, and that type is an instance of `Vehicle`'. IMHO, while one can make hetrogenous lists, and explicit foralls and all that, it often means something is wrong with the "layout" of the program.

Comment: But even if `Vehicle a => [a]` would mean you can make a list of both `Car`s and `Train`s, it is rather non-sensical to use it. Why? Because then we lose track that these are `Car`s and `Train`s. Now you would think you might want to call the function `drive` for example that is defined on the `Vehicle`s for example, but then why not generate a list of the `drive`s of these vehicles, so if `drive` is `Vehicle v => v -> Coord -> Coord`, just make a list of `[Coord -> Coord]` that contains the `drive myTrain` and `drive myCar`.

Comment: [an article on the existential antipattern and how to avoid it](http://web.archive.org/web/20100301045845/https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short: *don't do this*. Keep it simple. What you probably want is something like

```
data Vehicle = Car | Bicycle | ...

break :: [Vehicle]
break = [Car]
```

or

```
data Vehicle = Vehicle { numberOfWheels :: Int
                       , topSpeed :: Double
                       , crashPavement :: Pedestrian -> Pedestrian
                       , ... }


break :: [Vehicle]
break = [car]
 where car = Vehicle 4 190 (\_ -> DeadPedestrian) ...
```

with some (possibly composite) concrete type with variants and record fields.

What you attempted, with signature `Vehicle a => [a]`, does something completely different: it declares that *the caller* of `break` gets to choose one type that is an instance of the `Vehicle` class, and then `break` needs to provide values of that type in the list. This is not what you want, and again not something you need since a simple alternative type already gets you there.

That said, in the unlikely event that an OO-like "container of subclass objects" is really appropriate for your use case, Haskell does support that too. It's called an *existential wrapper*:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

class Vehicle a 

data SomeVehicle where
  SomeVehicle :: Vehicle a => SomeVehicle

data Car = Car 
instance Vehicle Car

break :: [SomeVehicle]
break = [SomeVehicle Car]
```

Note that the resulting list will be almost completely useless, because there is no way to find out what particular type of vehicle each list element is. You'd need to add a lot of boilerplate-ish methods to the `Vehicle` class.